# ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_1/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Im using tf.keras to load a model I made previously with tf.keras but when I try to make the prediction I just get this

```
[ERROR] [1560045312.143498]: bad callback: <function callback at 0x7f16fe94b8c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/franky/catkin_ws_kinetic/src/tfm/scripts/nnet_predictor.py", line 50, in callback
    true_face.eyes[1].height
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1113, in predict
    self, x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 195, in model_iteration
    f = _make_execution_function(model, mode)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 122, in _make_execution_function
    return model._make_execution_function(mode)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1989, in _make_execution_function
    self._make_predict_function()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1979, in _make_predict_function
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3201, in function
    return GraphExecutionFunction(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 2939, in __init__
    with ops.control_dependencies(self.outputs):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5028, in control_dependencies
    return get_default_graph().control_dependencies(control_inputs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4528, in control_dependencies
    c = self.as_graph_element(c)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3478, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3557, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_1/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I also may say that I am using this in a ros framework (robot operating system [it is not an operating system, just have a super misleading name, I am on linux]) so I know that the callback() is being called in a thread and I can't avoid using ros.

Also I have tested that if I use the prediction function in the main thread, everything works fine.

I have already tried the `with graph.as_default():` and `clear_session()` solutions, but no luck.

I have already check that every import is from tf.keras and I'm not mixing tf.keras with keras

I also tried to use a Lock() to avoid having the predict() function being called 2+ at the same time

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
from tfm_msgs.msg import IsLooking
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.backend import clear_session
import tensorflow as tf
from threading import Thread, Lock
# other non relevant imports

def callback(face_array_stamped):
    global mutex
    mutex.acquire()
    try:
        global graph
        # with graph.as_default():
        global my_model
        global pub
        true_faces = []
        for face in face_array_stamped.faces:
            if len(face.eyes) == 2:
                true_faces.append(face)
        if len(true_faces) == 1:
            true_face = true_faces[0]
            prediction = my_model.predict(np.array([[
                #all the data here
                                        ]]))[0]
            #↑↑↑↑↑It crashes here↑↑↑↑↑↑
            #more non relevant stuff
    finally:
        mutex.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # clear_session()
    model_dir = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + "/../nnet_models/"
    json_file = open(model_dir+'model.json', 'r')
    my_model = model_from_json(json_file.read())
    json_file.close()
    my_model.load_weights(model_dir+'model.h5')
    # my_model._make_predict_function()
    my_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # my_model.summary()
```

I would expect the code not to crash

Comment: I would recommend exporting your graph and studying it with Tensorboard to see what is wrong with operation wiring. If you were able to train the model before saving and you did not recreate any ops after restoring everything should have been fine though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I couldn't figure out what's happening, I don't know if it's beacause of how ros works, but I ended up using the solution at 
[Execute Python function in Main thread from call in Dummy thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989446/execute-python-function-in-main-thread-from-call-in-dummy-thread)
so my code ended up like this:

```py
callback_queue = Queue.Queue()


def prediction_callback(true_face, face_header):
    #non relevant stuff
    prediction = my_model.predict(np.array([[
        #all the variables
        ]])
    #more non relevant stuff


def face_callback(face_array_stamped): #this is the original callback
    #...
    callback_queue.put(lambda: prediction_callback(true_face, face_array_stamped.header))
    #...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #...
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            callback_queue.get(True, 2)()
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `graph = tf.get_default_graph()` and `with graph.as_default():`

What about this?

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
from tfm_msgs.msg import IsLooking
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.backend import clear_session
import tensorflow as tf
from threading import Thread, Lock
# other non relevant imports


graph = tf.get_default_graph()


def callback(face_array_stamped):
    global mutex
    mutex.acquire()
    try:
        global my_model
        global pub
        true_faces = []
        for face in face_array_stamped.faces:
            if len(face.eyes) == 2:
                true_faces.append(face)
        if len(true_faces) == 1:
            true_face = true_faces[0]
            with graph.as_default():
                prediction = my_model.predict(np.array([[
                #all the data here
                                        ]]))[0]
            #↑↑↑↑↑It crashes here↑↑↑↑↑↑
            #more non relevant stuff
    finally:
        mutex.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # clear_session()
    model_dir = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + "/../nnet_models/"
    json_file = open(model_dir+'model.json', 'r')
    my_model = model_from_json(json_file.read())
    json_file.close()
    my_model.load_weights(model_dir+'model.h5')
    # my_model._make_predict_function()
    my_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # my_model.summary()
```

Comment: I have already tried this, and I got `FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable dense_1/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/dense_1/bias/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.` error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the solution above didn't work out for me. I wanted to subscribe an image and predict something with keras/tensorflow. Doing so, I got the same errors described above.

The following solution worked for me:

```
def method_to_predict(msg):
    # ...
    model.predict(...)
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('my_node', anonymous=False)

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        msg = rospy.wait_for_message('topic', msg_type)
        method_to_predict(msg)
```

Hope this helps if the solution above doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I am subscribing to a topic in ROS and in callback method calling `model.predict()`. Adding:

```
import tensorflow as tf

global graph,model
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

And

```
with graph.as_default():
            steering_angle = float(model.predict(cropped[None, :, :, :], batch_size=1))
```

To callback solved my problem, as *Nattaphon* advised.

*Tensorflow 1.12, Keras 2.0.6, Ubuntu 18.04*